# bound sw library on specific platform on linux

Tags: security, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

if we want to bound one software library on specific platform, which means the sw lib can only run on the specific platform, is there any method to do this?

we have some ideas about this:
specific-platform <--> driver <--> sw-library

specific-platform <--> driver: We can add some hw checking in driver, so that the driver can not be moved to other platform.

but, in driver <--> lib path, what if the hacker use one fake driver which can install on other platform and return some fake system calls, the lib can run on other platform.

i have no idea, how to make sure the driver and lib can bound together?
does RSA signsture help this?

any recommendations will be helpful, thanks.

Comment: Kernel drivers can be loaded only by root (or user with very high privileges). If hacker has such privileges, nothing can save your software from misusage.  Of course, many products uses some protections mechanisms, which make incorrect usage **more difficult**. But I am unsure that they will share this mechanism with you.

Comment: thanks for the comment, we are  one design house company, we just want to make sure our sw algorithm library can only run on our platform. For preventing the customer use the sw algorithm on other platform. But it seems hard to protect this :(